# System.NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required

Tags: android, xamarin

my app crash and give this log

> Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object
>
> SQLClient.GetAllProfile ()
>
> Comman.get_Profile ()

my code is
comman.cs

```
 public static Profile Profile {
        get {
            if (_profile == null) {
                var profiles = SQLClient.Instance.GetAllProfile ();
                if (profiles!=null && profiles.Count > 0) {
                    _profile = profiles [0];
                }
            }

            return _profile;
        }
        set {
            _profile = value;
        }
  }
```

and in SQLClient.cs

```
    public List<Profile> GetAllProfile()
    {
        lock (SQLClient.SyncObject)
        {
            List<Profile> list = conn.Table<Profile>().ToList(); 
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information - e.g. which line does it occur on?

Answer (score 0):

Either the SQLClient.SyncObject or the conn.GetTable method return a null value.
Did you check with your debugger?